# Get response body in Kong access log

Tags: nginx, lua, kong

I want to retrieve request and response body logs from Kong api manager.
I have added new plugin (udp-log plugin) to kong, to get stream logs in Graylog dashboard.
According to this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/361556/is-it-possible-to-log-the-response-data-in-nginx-access-log/479123#479123) I have tried to setup my nginx-kong.conf file in /usr/local/kong directory and I have added new variable in my `log-serializers/basic.lua` file like this:

```
response = {
  status = ngx.status,
  headers = ngx.resp.get_headers(),
  size = ngx.var.bytes_sent,
  req_body = ngx.var.req_body,
  test = ngx.var.resp_body,
},
```

then after this config, I have created new `nginx.template` file according to this [second link](https://getkong.org/docs/0.13.x/configuration/#serving-both-a-website-and-your-apis-from-kong)

When I send a request to api endpoint through port 8000 (default api port of  kong) I got a null response for `resp_body` variable but I can log full response (response body included) when I try to send request through another port (for example 8500). 
Is there any solution?